# How to copy the contents of one 2d array to another? (VBA)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compiler-errors

My current code looks like this:

```
Dim Array1(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
Dim Array2(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
Array1(1, 1) = "A"
Array1(1, 2) = "B"
Array1(2, 1) = 1
Array1(2, 2) = "C"
Array2 = Array1
```

This however returns a "Compile Error: Can't assign to array"

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `Dim Array2() As Variant`.

Comment: @BigBen: Yes, this is the solution. Even if `Dim Array2`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A double loop:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim Array1(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim Array2(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    
    Array1(1, 1) = "A"
    Array1(1, 2) = "B"
    Array1(2, 1) = 1
    Array1(2, 2) = "C"
    
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 2
            Array2(i, j) = Array1(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Or you can cheat:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    Dim Array1(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim Array2
    Dim r As Range
    
    Set r = Range("A1:B2")
    
    Array1(1, 1) = "A"
    Array1(1, 2) = "B"
    Array1(2, 1) = 1
    Array1(2, 2) = "C"
    
    r = Array1
    Array2 = r
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

BigBen's proposed solution works and it probably the best approach.

Comment: @VBasic2008  I agree with BigBen.